# When using array to name input fields in HTML -- how to count array length?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dom

Let's say I have some html that looks like this:

```
<input type="text" name="myInputs[]"> 
<br>
<input type="text" name="myInputs[]"> 
<br>
<input type="text" name="myInputs[]"> 
<br>
```

I want to use the length of the myInputs array inside some JavaScript code. How do I extract the length of this array? myInputs.length doesn't seem to work

Comment: You have tried accessing it through the form? `myform.myInputs.length`?

Comment: Put them in a form then `theform['myInputs[]'].length`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
console.log(document.formName.elements["myInputs[]"].length);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
document.querySelectorAll("[name='myInputs[]']").length
```

You can also call `querySelectorAll` on the form element itself